# ASP.NET Many Nested Controls

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have 2 Repeaters one inside another.

```
<div id="result">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="results">
        <Itemtemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Color"></asp:Button>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server">
                <Itemtemplate>
                    <tr class="gradeX odd">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Add Size"></asp:Button>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                </Itemtemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
        </Itemtemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

And on PageLoad I am populating both with DataBinding to List and List. The Button1 and Button2 is responsible for adding rows to each Repeater when clicked. The code is adding the rows to both perfectly but I noticed when I click the Buttons the data from the textbox isn't posted to the server so I collect from code behind. Is there something wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you re-bind your data on page postback as well. Page control tree needs to be recreated before you can access the posted values.

If you re-create and add the control in page_load, it would allow you to access the post back value, but any view state changes *may* get lost/over written.

If you can, then recreating the control tree in page_init results in cleanest solution as it would allow the dynamic controls view state to restored properly.

Read this excellent article on [Dynamic Web Controls, Postbacks, and View State](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx)

> **Adding Controls at the Right Time**
>
> We already know that when adding controls dynamically through the page's code portion the controls must be added on every postback. But when in the page lifecycle should the controls be added? At first guess, we might decide to put such code in the Page_Load event handler, causing the controls to be added during the Load stage of the page's lifecycle. This would work fine if we don't need to worry about saving the controls' view state across postbacks, but if we do need to persist the view state of the dynamically added controls the Load stage is not where we should be adding these controls.

See following for [The ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic2)

Comment: No I am just populating when it's not Postback on page load.

Comment: The problem is, buttons should send data to server.

Comment: @Umair Ashraf: Control needs to be created and part of the page's control tree only then LoadPostData() is called. If you _somehow_ add the control to page control tree (rebinding), you should be able to access the post back data.

Comment: See [The ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic2) for details.

Comment: But you know what, the first Repeaters child controls do send data to server on post back. It's only nested repeater which can not send the data. The first repeater is bound on Page_Load and as soon as it gets populated the second Repeater is bound on Item_Bound event of first Repeater.

Comment: I partially solved the problem by moving actions to Page_Load event which re-populate the repeater. But still working to fix completely.

Comment: @Umar not sure what you mean by 'the first Repeaters child controls do send data to server on post back'. As per your template first repeater control has only buttons in it. If you can explain the other problem in detail we may attempt to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the server to read in the posted data, all ASP server controls have to exist right after `Page_Init`.  Controls that do not exist at that point are not "deserialized", aka given values that were sent by the browser.  Controls you create in `Page_Load` only arrive after the deserialization party.

Does it work if you move the `DataBind` from `Page_Load` to `Page_Init`?

Comment: not right after `Page_Init`, but before end of `Page_Load`. Also, just existing is not enough, they should be part of page control tree as well. If @Umair binds the control (create) it in page_load every time, it would work.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser: Well, if I follow the link you posted to the life cycle page, it says that `LoadPostbackData` is called before `Page_Load`.  I'm pretty sure that's correct, as I've had to explain this to most new developers on our team :)

Comment: it's different for Dynamic controls. Best place to add them is page_init, but if they are added before end of page_load, it would still work. Its rather simple to test :). Mean while I'll try to find a _link_ that explains it better. Also, it may impact the view state; control loosing properties changed in code behind from previous states but not user entered values.